# How to build till-end array sampler with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some `np.array`:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(7)
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I want to get all splitting keys that have some minimum length of second part and lasts in the same point as original.

```
>>> do_what_i_want(arr, 3):
[
    [[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
    [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
    [[0, 1], [2, 3 ,4, 5, 6]],
    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]],
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
]
```

I need to implement `do_what_i_want()` function

**UPD**
My current code:

```
def till_end_transform(self, arr, n):
    I = np.arange(n) + np.arange(arr.shape[0] - n + 1).reshape(-1, 1)
    # A[I]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-with-arrays-of-indices
    # B is list of num_of_features-dimenstional charts
    B = A[I].reshape(-1, M * A.shape[1], A.shape[2])
    return B
```

Comment: What's the code you currently have for this loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build till-end array sampler with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947777/how-to-build-till-end-array-sampler-with-numpy)

Comment: Yes, sorry, my site lagged and I've posted the question twice. My current code is included to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want you can use comprehension:

```
def do_what_i_want(arr, k):
    return [[arr[:i], arr[i:]] for i in range(len(arr)-k+1)]
```

Which produces:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
do_what_i_want(a, 3)
#[[[], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
# [[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
# [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]],
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python functions are defined using the `def` keyword. For example:

```
def hello(name):
    print('Hello, %s' % name)

hello('UIUAA')
```

I've found pretty good examples examples to arrays and functions on this webpage:

http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#python-functions

http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy-arrays

Hope i could help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `np.split`:

```
def splitter(arr, val):
    return [np.split(arr, [i]) for i in range(val+1)]
```

```
>>> splitter(np.arange(7), 3)
[[array([], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
 [array([0]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
 [array([0, 1]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
 [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5, 6])]]
```